# Android double and, &&

Tags: java, android

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null && 'v' == line.charAt(0) ) 
{
   // perform your task here

    String[] separated = line.split(" ");
    Log.d("bbb", separated[0].toString());
}

07-02 23:17:42.127: E/Trace(14343): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-02 23:17:42.127: D/ActivityThread(14343): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-02 23:17:42.127: D/ActivityThread(14343): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-02 23:17:42.127: D/ActivityThread(14343): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-02 23:17:42.167: D/aaa(14343): It worked!
07-02 23:17:42.337: D/libEGL(14343): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-02 23:17:42.337: D/libEGL(14343): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-02 23:17:42.337: D/libEGL(14343): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
07-02 23:17:42.397: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(14343): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
07-02 23:17:42.417: E/(14343): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
07-02 23:17:42.417: E/(14343): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
07-02 23:17:42.417: D/OpenGLRenderer(14343): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Addition of the double and seems to be stopping the reading process of the stream. If I remove the "&& 'v' == line.charAt(0)" it works fine and gives this output:

```
07-02 23:17:42.127: E/Trace(14343): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-02 23:17:42.127: D/ActivityThread(14343): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-02 23:17:42.127: D/ActivityThread(14343): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-02 23:17:42.127: D/ActivityThread(14343): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-02 23:17:42.167: D/aaa(14343): It worked!
07-02 23:17:42.337: D/libEGL(14343): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-02 23:17:42.337: D/libEGL(14343): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-02 23:17:42.337: D/libEGL(14343): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
07-02 23:17:42.397: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(14343): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
07-02 23:17:42.417: E/(14343): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
07-02 23:17:42.417: E/(14343): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
07-02 23:17:42.417: D/OpenGLRenderer(14343): Enabling debug mode 0
07-02 23:20:47.264: E/Trace(14481): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-02 23:20:47.264: D/ActivityThread(14481): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-02 23:20:47.264: D/ActivityThread(14481): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-02 23:20:47.264: D/ActivityThread(14481): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/aaa(14481): It worked!
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): #
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): #
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): #
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): #
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): #
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): v
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): v
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): v
07-02 23:20:47.304: D/bbb(14481): v
07-02 23:20:47.314: D/bbb(14481): v
```

Comment: So, if you don't need `&& 'v' == line.charAt(0)` why did you put it there?

Comment: I am trying to check for lines starting with 'v' only....

Comment: Consider removing unnecessary output from your question. Leave only the output produced by the problematic code snippet. Also, it would help if you provide sample input here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is: How do I only process lines starting with `v`? Then change:

```
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null && 'v' == line.charAt(0) )
```

to

```
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     if (line.trim().startsWith("v") ) {
         ...
     }
}
```

The code before would exit the loop *as soon* as a non v character shows up

Comment: The code I changed but there is no output in the log for any lines starting with v and there is some errors.

Comment: The log essentially turns into the first log entry in my post when I run the startsWith("v") code...

Comment: Maybe there is whitespace before the v? check my updated answer.

Comment: If I put a if(line.startsWith("v")) inside the while loop then it works. Whith the double && I can't get anything to function...

Comment: Then thats what needs to happen. See the answer.